# Need to implement mail merge by using Aspose word with java for normal fields as well as tables

Tags: java, field, mailmerge, aspose.words

We are using java spring boot project, and implemented a REST API to perform a aspose word mail merge.

Input to REST : Word file (containing mail merge fields, tables), JSON body (values required to merge)
Output : mail merged Word file.

For mail merge of normal fields in word, we are successfully able to do it with JSON input.

Where as, I analyzed that, for mail merge of table, we need to provide the input in specific XML file.
Is it possible to mail merge tables with method executeWithRegions() with JSON input? or input in XML is must?

Current implementation :

I have used "JSON INPUT" receiving from REST to perform mail merge of "Normal Fields"
And
I have to provide a hardcoded xml file to perform mail merge for "TABLE" in the same word document.(which is not useful for dynamic mail merge)

This is not a good solution to execute mail merge option twice,
1 for normal fields with JSON input.
2 for TABLES with XML file input.

Whereas, we are not getting any XML data as input. We are just getting JSON object as below,

[image]

In above input :

1. Normal fields : title, header.
2. Tables : Table1.

Java code implemented :

[image]

Is it possible to use only JSON for mail merge of normal fields and tables?
or is it possible to convert JSON to XML and to use XML as a common input for both normal fields and tables?

Also,
table mail merge requires XML format as,

[image]

where as standard XML document with converter provides XML format as,

[image]

Also if we are adding normal mail merge fields in XML file, then it is not performing mail merge of normal fields, it is performing mail merge of tables only.

Kindly suggest the better solution.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

It is not the must to use XML as a data source to execute mail merge with regions. In your case you should use [IMailMergeDataSource](https://reference.aspose.com/words/java/com.aspose.words/imailmergedatasource/). Using it you can use any object as data source for executing mail merge.